# Connect Flutter app with abp.io framework

Tags: flutter, asp.net-core, abp

Hi we are trying to connect our flutter app with abp.io framework.

We are facing hiccups in connecting the auth framework. We are able to open the web url from flutter and able to login. But after login it redirects to swagger.

We believe we have given the redirect uri in asp.net core api's dbmigrator, Identity server Data seeder  and also in angular's environments

Here is the github issue following to the convo https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/8723

Here is the steps we have followed. https://github.com/Znow/znow.github.io/blob/master/_posts/2021-04-23-consume-abp-api-from-flutter-app.md

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I created a youtube tutorial for this with login and logout working with `openid_client` package in flutter.

Here is the blogpost : https://blog.antosubash.com/posts/abp-auth-with-flutter-p5

Youtube video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lQEVvKzX6P8

This works with Android and Windows.

Solution from @Znow also works well. this is a alternative for `flutter_appauth` package. The only problem I had the with the `flutter_appauth` is logout look at this issue https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_appauth/issues/48 and that is what made me look for other solution.